# How to change the column value in XSLT?

Tags: html, xslt

I have the status in the third column but its value is coming on the first column... How do I change that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Artist</th>
    <th>status</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[artist='Bob Dylan']">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
 <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd/dude" >
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="status"/></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
 </body>
   </html>
 </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Basically it's coming out like:

```
Title              Artist       status
Empire Burlesque   Bob Dylan
hello
```

I want:

```
Title              Artist       status
Empire Burlesque   Bob Dylan    hello
```

How do I go about doing that?

This is the source XML:

```
<catalog> 
    <cd> 
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title> 
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist> 
        <country>USA</country> 
        <company>Columbia</company> 
        <price>10.90</price> 
        <year>1985</year> 
        <dude> 
            <status>hello</status> 
        </dude> 
    </cd> 
</catalog>
```

Comment: It looks like you are saying you want the same thing you are getting.  Even in the comment above it seems this way.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy -->
<catalog>
 <cd>
  <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
  <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company>Columbia</company>
  <price>10.90</price>
  <year>1985</year>
 
                <dude>
                     <status>hello</status>
                </dude>
</cd>
 
</catalog>

Comment: You should put your code examples in the question.

Comment: thats the XML above^ if you add it on this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_filter) you will see what I am talking about the hello comes on the first column instead of status which is what needs to be changed

Comment: Are there many status? Or only one in the `dude` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were creating a separate row for `status`. Since you have three columns in one row, you should add the `dude` column together with the other two to obtain what you desire:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
         <th>Title</th>
         <th>Artist</th>
         <th>status</th>
    </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[artist='Bob Dylan']">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="dude/status"/></td>
        </tr>
     </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

This iterates in all `cd` elements which contain an `artist` child element with the text `Bod Dylan`, and when it finds one, it adds a `<tr>` table row containing three `<td>` table cells which are your columns.

The way you were doing it iterated in all `dude` elements (there is only one) and placed the contents of the `status` element in a new `<tr>` row. That's why you got an extra row.